# Scala compiler infers Nothing for generic arguments

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, type-inference, slick

I'm trying something that I've seen in different shapes in different contexts before:
extending scala's query extensions with `filterById(id: Id)`

This is what I've tried:

```
trait TableWithId { self: Profile =>

    import profile.simple._

    trait HasId[Id] { self: Table[_] =>
      def id: Column[Id]
    }

    implicit class HasIdQueryExt[Id: BaseColumnType, U]
    (query: Query[Table[U] with HasId[Id], U]) {
      def filterById(id: Id)(implicit s: Session) = query.filter(_.id === id)
      def insertReturnId(m: U)(implicit s: Session): Id = query.returning(query.map(_.id)) += m
    }
}
```

This works fine, no real magic there. But because there is no type constraint on the Table type, any query to which I apply filterById, looses it's specificness (is is now a generic `Table with HasId[Id]`), and I can no longer reach it's columns (except for `_.id` ofcourse).

I don't know how to type this implicit conversion, such that this is prevented. Is it possible? The following "naieve" solution does not work, because Scala infers Nothing for the Id type  now:

```
implicit class HasIdQueryExt[Id: BaseColumnType, U, T <: Table[U] with HasId[Id]]
(query: Query[T, U]) { ... }
```

I find it kind of strange that suddenly the Id type is inferred as Nothing. How do I hint the compiler where to look for that Id type?

Comment: I am not familiar with Slick, but my guess is, that your solution would require a generic parameter that takes the actual type of your table... something like 'HasId[Id, T <: HasId[Id, T]]'. Then you can pass the actual type of the table with HasId as parameter T. Edit: Also, have you tried using structural types? http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural This will use reflection, but still give you static safety.

Comment: I don't see how that is different from the approach that I wrote down last. Aren't those equivalent? And I don't think that structural typing helps in this case. The problem retains it's structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for a similar problem. I did use specific type for id though.:

```
trait GenericComponent { this: Profile =>
  import profile.simple._

  abstract class TableWithId[A](tag:Tag, name:String) extends Table[A](tag:Tag, name) {
    def id = column[Option[UUID]]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  }

  abstract class genericTable[T <: Table[A] , A] {
    val table: TableQuery[T]

    /**
     * generic methods
     */

    def insert(entry: A)(implicit session:Session): A = session.withTransaction { 
      table += entry
      entry
    }

    def insertAll(entries: List[A])(implicit session:Session) = session.withTransaction { table.insertAll(entries:_*) }

    def all: List[A] = database.withSession { implicit session =>
      table.list.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
    }
  }

  /**
   * generic queries for any table which has id:Option[UUID]
   */
  abstract class genericTableWithId[T <: TableWithId[A], A <:ObjectWithId ] extends genericTable[T, A] {

    def forIds(ids:List[UUID]): List[A] = database.withSession { implicit session =>
      ids match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case x::xs =>table.filter(_.id inSet(ids)).list.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
      }
    }

    def forId(id:UUID):Option[A] = database.withSession { implicit session =>table.filter(_.id === id).firstOption }

  }
}
```

and then for your concrete component:

```
case class SomeObjectRecord(
  override val id:Option[UUID] = None,
  name:String) extends ObjectWithId(id){
  // your function definitions there
} 

trait SomeObjectComponent extends GenericComponent { this: Profile =>
  import profile.simple._

  class SomeObjects(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[SomeObjectRecord](tag, "some_objects") {
    def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)

    def * = (id, name) <> (SomeObjectRecord.tupled, SomeObjectRecord.unapply)
    def nameIdx = index("u_name", (name), unique = true)
  }

  object someobjects extends genericTableWithId[SomeObjects, SomeObjectRecord] {
    val table = TableQuery[Units]

   // your additional methods there; you get insert and insertAll from the parent    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this ofcourse does not answer my question; it works around the problem. Because what you are suggesting is: remove the Id generic parameter. Additionally, I prefer QueryExtensions over your companion object with methods, because extensions on Queries can be reused wherever a query gives a certain result shape, whereas your additional methods can only be used an-sich.